# Rest call failed with client error, status code 406 NotAcceptable

Tags: json, azure, rest, azure-data-factory

When I test with Advanced Rest Client(Arc) all nine API calls to REST API works fine.
I use method Get with two headers the first is Authorization Bearer
the second one is Content-type application/json. It works even if I remove
header Content-type application/json
Here is a screenshot of the response from Arc. This same REST API call give error from Azure Data Factory(ADF).
[Sceenshot from Arc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3zO8.png)
I call nine REST API from Azure Data Factory(ADF) with the same base url but different Relative URL.
Out of these nine 6 works perfect.
When I use Azure Data Factory(ADF) I use additional header
Authorization Bearer @{activity('GetToken').output.access}
What is strange is that the exact same call from Arc works fine but I get error when I call from ADF. Note also that I get the exact same error if I remove the additional header
Authorization Bearer @{activity('GetToken').output.access}
I mean that the code in REST API doesn't know if the call is comming from Arc or ADF.

Note also the the error is from the source side so my call to REST API with method GET
can't be handled by the REST API code for some reason.
According to the documentation for the REST API it says that
Headers Content-type application/json and
Authorization Bearer 
I tried to add a second additional header in ADF Headers Content-type application/json
but I get REST connector ignores any "Content-Type" header specified in additional headers when request body is empty.
I have tried to find any sensible information about my error but there no one that have had any similar. What I find very strange is that 6 Rest API calls works fine and the json that we receive when using Arc is valid.
I don't realy understand the error message when saying
Requested format \u0022application/json\u0022 is not supported
Supported MIME types are \u0022application/ld+json\u0022
Here is the complete error message I get [Screen shot of error message for ADF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYHCD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your response data is JSON LD (Json linked data). Hence you are seeing this error.

> To avoid this error use `Content-Type` header value as `application/ld+json`.